# Dynamic Oracle Procedure - issue with structure

Tags: sql, oracle

I seem to be having some issues around creating a stored procedure and I simply cannot see where the issue lies. I am relatively new to Oracle.

I have a table of unknown length. What I have done is I created a stored procedure that will create a table to the width of the row count of the table where I am getting my values from. i.e. if the table has 10 values, the code will create a new table 10 columns wide, etc.

I have managed to get the initial code working, but now I am trying to add some additional logic without success.

My logic that I am trying to accomplish is as such:

IF TABLE DOES NOT EXIST - CREATE IT

IF TABLE EXSITS - SIMPLY INSERT INTO IT

I have not created the code for the INSERT part yet as I cannot get the first part to work. Everything was working fine until I added the count and IF statement.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MDWPROD"."WORKFLOW_VAR_PIVOT" IS
    v_sql varchar2(32767);

    -- for the first run ofthe procedure, we need to create the table
    DECLARE var_count INT;

    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    INTO 
        var_count
    FROM 
        all_tables 
    WHERE 
        OWNER = 'MDWPROD'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'RBI_PROCESSVARIABLE_WK';


    -- if var_count = 0 then the table does not exists, create it, otherwise proceed with other logic
    IF var_count = 0 THEN

        -- cursor to find out the maximum number of projected columns required
        CURSOR cur_proj_test IS
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                ID, 
                VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL
            FROM   
                MDWPROD.RBI_VARIABLETYPE_DM
            ORDER BY 
                ID;

         -- We now loop through the cursor, and build of the SQL string to CREATE and POPULATE the table 
        BEGIN
            v_sql := 'CREATE TABLE MDWPROD.RBI_PROCESSVARIABLE_WK AS SELECT VAR.PROCESS_ID';
            FOR i IN cur_proj_test
            LOOP

                -- dynamically add to the projection for the query
                v_sql := v_sql || ',MAX(CASE VT.VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL WHEN ''' || i.VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL || ''' THEN VAR.VALUE ELSE '''' END) AS "' || i.VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL || '"';

            END LOOP;

            v_sql := v_sql || ' FROM MDWPROD.RBI_VARIABLE_DM VAR INNER JOIN MDWPROD.RBI_VARIABLETYPE_DM VT ON VAR.VARIABLE_TYPE_ID = VT.ID WHERE VAR.CURRENT_IND = ''Y'' GROUP BY VAR.PROCESS_ID order by VAR.PROCESS_ID';

             -- Create table and populate it with all the relevant variable values
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
        END;


    END IF;
END;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Original working proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WORKFLOW_VAR_PIVOT IS
    v_sql varchar2(32767);


    -- cursor to find out the maximum number of projected columns required
    CURSOR cur_proj_test IS
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            ID, 
            VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL
        FROM   
            MDWPROD.RBI_VARIABLETYPE_DM
        ORDER BY 
            ID;

     -- We now loop through the cursor, and build of the SQL string to CREATE and POPULATE the table 
    BEGIN
        v_sql := 'CREATE TABLE MDWPROD.RBI_PROCESSVARIABLE AS SELECT VAR.PROCESS_ID';
        FOR i IN cur_proj_test
        LOOP

            -- dynamically add to the projection for the query
            v_sql := v_sql || ',MAX(CASE VT.VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL WHEN ''' || i.VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL || ''' THEN VAR.VALUE ELSE '''' END) AS "' || i.VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL || '"';

        END LOOP;

        v_sql := v_sql || ' FROM MDWPROD.RBI_VARIABLE_DM VAR INNER JOIN MDWPROD.RBI_VARIABLETYPE_DM VT ON VAR.VARIABLE_TYPE_ID = VT.ID WHERE VAR.CURRENT_IND = ''Y'' GROUP BY VAR.PROCESS_ID order by VAR.PROCESS_ID';

        -- un comment this line to print out the entire SQL statement
        -- dbms_output.put_line('Dynamic SQL Statement:-' || chr(10) || v_sql || chr(10) || chr(10));

        -- DROP TABLE before recreating it
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE MDWPROD.RBI_PROCESSVARIABLE';

        -- Create table and populate it with all the relevant variable values
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
    END;
```

Comment: You didn't specify how it's not working.  Is there an error?

Comment: The first step you should do here is to look at the SQL string that you're building, and see if it works on its own. That ought to tell you where you are going wrong.

Comment: as i mentioned, the orig proc is working without issue. Yes, I have outputted the string and run it stand alone and it works perfectly fine. The error (unknown to me) only occurs when I add the SELECT COUNT(*) along with the IF statement.

Comment: ...but you never stated ***what*** the error message is.  It's kind of useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other problems (you never stated your exact error), but I can immediately see that the `begin` keyword is in the wrong place. Your declarations should be at the top, before the `begin` keyword, and your execution statements should come after.

I moved things around a little.  This should get you closer to your goal:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MDWPROD"."WORKFLOW_VAR_PIVOT" IS
    v_sql varchar2(32767);

    -- for the first run ofthe procedure, we need to create the table
    DECLARE var_count INT;

    -- cursor to find out the maximum number of projected columns required
    CURSOR cur_proj_test IS
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            ID, 
            VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL
        FROM   
            MDWPROD.RBI_VARIABLETYPE_DM
        ORDER BY 
            ID;

BEGIN

    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    INTO 
        var_count
    FROM 
        all_tables 
    WHERE 
        OWNER = 'MDWPROD'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'RBI_PROCESSVARIABLE_WK';


    -- if var_count = 0 then the table does not exists, create it, otherwise proceed with other logic
    IF var_count = 0 THEN


         -- We now loop through the cursor, and build of the SQL string to CREATE and POPULATE the table 
            v_sql := 'CREATE TABLE MDWPROD.RBI_PROCESSVARIABLE_WK AS SELECT VAR.PROCESS_ID';
            FOR i IN cur_proj_test
            LOOP

                -- dynamically add to the projection for the query
                v_sql := v_sql || ',MAX(CASE VT.VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL WHEN ''' || i.VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL || ''' THEN VAR.VALUE ELSE '''' END) AS "' || i.VARIABLE_REPORT_LBL || '"';

            END LOOP;

            v_sql := v_sql || ' FROM MDWPROD.RBI_VARIABLE_DM VAR INNER JOIN MDWPROD.RBI_VARIABLETYPE_DM VT ON VAR.VARIABLE_TYPE_ID = VT.ID WHERE VAR.CURRENT_IND = ''Y'' GROUP BY VAR.PROCESS_ID order by VAR.PROCESS_ID';

             -- Create table and populate it with all the relevant variable values
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to reply, was off sick on Friday. Thank you, this did help set me on the right track. I did encounter another error, but simply removing the "DECLARE" resolved that.